# Ubuntu 19.10 Grub options not shown

Tags: grub2

I just installed ubuntu 19.10 today. it's succesfully installed and i can enter ubuntu and windows 10. however, the options for the menut not shown. I have to press a down arrow and enter in blank screen to enter windows (it means the grub option is running but there is no disply).

What I have done:

1. boot repair
2. Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`
3. use this `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`  in windows

but nothing change...
do you have another suggestion how to show grub menu

Thank you

Comment: did you install windows first or ubuntu first?

Comment: I install windows first

Comment: Do you remember to run after: sudo update-grub

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it seems like the signed version of grub shimx64.efi can't load any font. To show the menu I renamed the file unicode.pf2 in /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fonts. This way grub2 will use system font, the drawback is that you will see question marks in place of extended chars. The unsigned version of grub grubx64.efi works well but it can't load unsigned kernels even though secure boot is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem also. 
On the very same machine I have a hard disk with Ubuntu 18.04 installed on it alongside same copy of Windows also. This disk is fine when used and the Grub menu shows.
if I switch disks, no more menu... 
I will try to see what is the font problem by checking both fonts on both disks.
BTW, I have another machine running also secure boot and 19.10 and the menu displays fine (but the machine is a different make and different EFI Bios)
**Update :**
As I have some machines running Ubuntu 18-04 and Secure Boot, I checked the file unicode.pf2. They are different in 18.04 and 19.10.
I tried to use the file from 18.04 in lieu of the file which came from 19.10. Same result.
So for now, rename /boot/grub/unicode.pf2 to something else and also /boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2 and the menu will show. Albeit with an ugly face.
Next step is to see what Grub2 package is used in 18-04 and 19-10 and see if we can safely switch from the new back to the old....